# 500 Internal server error django java

Tags: java, django, python-2.7

I am sending a Java post request(JSON object) from my Java app to my Django app(in same machine).

My code for java request part is:

```
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(myurl);
    String json = jsonobject;

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json,"UTF-8");
    entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    post.setEntity(entity);
    try {
        HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post);
        LOGGER.info("Reached " + response1);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And my Python views function is as follows:

```
@csrf_exempt
def rcvr1(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        try:
            return StreamingHttpResponse("here")
        except:
            return StreamingHttpResponse("not Here")

    return StreamingHttpResponse("Unsuccessful")
```

The post request from Java is hitting the server, but is giving error:

> HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR [Date: Wed, 07 Jan 2015 14:00:11
>   GMT, Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN,
>   Content-Type: text/html]

Comment: add DEBUG=True in your settings.py to see the error

Comment: It is already true, but where does the error show ?

Comment: It would be in the response, you could dump more from your java client but since it fails before even checking `POST` you could also check it with your browser via a `GET`

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a string into [StreamingHttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects), it needs to be a generator.

Until you make that change you can test the above by using an [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) instead.

```
HttpResponse("Your text here")
```

Comment: No change, i even added print "check" before my if request.method=="POST",  it is not printing "check" and it is still giving the same error
07/Jan/2015 16:04:51] "POST /jsonabc HTTP/1.1" 500 69625 - terminal(where django server is being run)

and the above mentioned where java code is being run

Comment: okay, i would recommend having `DEBUG=True` in your settings as suggested on answer and hitting that URL with a GET since that print should run either way. Also if you have any non-standard middleware you should list it in your question. Finally check that you are importing everything you are referencing.